# PHP - Select a unique mysql line without while

Tags: php

I want to select only unique values with php/mysql.

I can do it with many line, but I forget how to do it without while... :)

Thanks a lot.

Here is the code that I want to do without while.

```
$request_1m = "SELECT date1, date2 from mytable";

$result_1m = mysql_query($request_1m,$db);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_1m))
{
    /* Get the data from the query result */    
    $date1_1m = $row["date1"];
    $date2_1m = $row["date2"];  
}
```

Comment: You're going to need the `while` loop to load your mysql result resource into an associative or numeric indexed array with `mysql_fetch_assoc`.  Are you looking for a single function call to get all results from your mysql result resource?  `SELECT DISTINCT column FROM table` will get your unique values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but here's what I think you want to do :

```
$request_1m = "SELECT date1, date2 from mytable";

$result_1m = mysql_query($request_1m,$db);

list($date1_1m, $date2_1m) = mysql_fetch_row($result_1m);
```

Note that this will only get the first row from the result set (just as if you LIMIT 1)

Comment: Yes, I have only one result in my query. 
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If you only had one row, you never needed a while loop in the first place.  A single call like `$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_1m);` would have done it.

Answer (score 3):

[mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) + [SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) with `DISTINCT`

Comment: I know nothing about your problem so I cannot provide you any code. Global examples you have in references.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
$dbresult = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT field FROM table");

$result = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult))
{
     $result[] = $row;
}
```

This gets you all unique values from "field" in table "table".

Comment: No, I don't want to use a while boucle ! 

I have added my code sample. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wish to avoid the `while` loop, you can use the PHP PDO objects, and in particular call the PDO `fetchAll()` method to retrieve the complete results array in one go.  [PDO fetchAll() documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

```
$db = new PDO('dblib:host=your_hostname;otherparams...');
$db->query("SELECT DISTINCT col FROM table");
$results = $db->fetchAll();

// All your result rows are now in $results
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres how I do it and Json encode after. This will ensure it will encode only UNIQUE json Values (Without duplicates) as an example

```
$tbl_nm = "POS_P";
$prod_cat = "prod_cat";

//Select from the POS_P Table the Unique Product Categories using the DISTINCT syntax
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT $prod_cat FROM $tbl_nm";

//Store the SQL query into the products variable below.
$products = mysql_query($sql);

if ($products){

    // Create an array
    $rows = array(); 

    // Fetch and populate array
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($products)) { 

    $rows[]=$row; 

    } 

    // Convert array to json format
    $json = json_encode(array('Categories'=>$rows));
    echo $json;

}
//Close db connection when done
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is very easy, take out the while, like below

```
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 $date1_1m = $row["date1"];
```